# How can I pass a parameter to a t-sql script?

Tags: sql, oracle, unix

```
CREATE TABLE DMS_POP_WKLY_REFRESH_20100201 NOLOGGING PARALLEL AS
SELECT wk.*,bbc.distance_km ,NVL(bbc.tactical_broadband_offer,0) tactical_broadband_offer ,
       sel.tactical_select_executive_flag,
       sel.agent_name,
       res.DMS_RESIGN_CAMPAIGN_CODE,
       pclub.tactical_select_flag
FROM   spineowner.pop_wkly_refresh_20100201 wk,
       dms_bb_coverage_102009 bbc,
       dms_select_executive_group sel,
       DMS_RESIGN_CAMPAIGN_26052009 res,
       DMS_PRIORITY_CLUB pclub
WHERE  wk.mpn = bbc.mpn(+)
AND    wk.mpn = sel.mpn (+)
AND    wk.mpn = res.mpn (+)
AND    wk.mpn = pclub.mpn (+)
```

vijay.sql  ( name given to above sql script)

How can I pass a parameter for 20100201 in side the sql script? I need to change every time this date format.

How can I call this sql script and run it in unix by passing date as parameter? So that date in the script should be modified in every run.

Answer (score 23):

SQL*Plus uses &1, &2... &n to access the parameters.

Suppose you have the following script `test.sql`:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SPOOL test.log
EXEC dbms_output.put_line('&1 &2');
SPOOL off
```

you could call this script like this for example:

```
$ sqlplus login/pw @test Hello World!
```

#### Edit:

In a UNIX script you would usually call a SQL script like this:

```
sqlplus /nolog << EOF
connect user/password@db
@test.sql Hello World!
exit
EOF
```

so that your login/password won't be visible with another session's `ps`

Comment: $ sqlplus uname/pwd@connectingstring @test.sql Hello World!

is the above command is same as u gave as example?

Comment: @user270203: I updated my answer with an example of how you could call such a SQL script from a UNIX script

Answer (score 1):

Two options 
save vijay.sql

```
declare
begin
execute immediate 
'CREATE TABLE DMS_POP_WKLY_REFRESH_'||to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD')||' NOLOGGING PARALLEL AS
SELECT wk.*,bbc.distance_km ,NVL(bbc.tactical_broadband_offer,0) tactical_broadband_offer ,
       sel.tactical_select_executive_flag,
       sel.agent_name,
       res.DMS_RESIGN_CAMPAIGN_CODE,
       pclub.tactical_select_flag
FROM   spineowner.pop_wkly_refresh_20100201 wk,
       dms_bb_coverage_102009 bbc,
       dms_select_executive_group sel,
       DMS_RESIGN_CAMPAIGN_26052009 res,
       DMS_PRIORITY_CLUB pclub
WHERE  wk.mpn = bbc.mpn(+)
AND    wk.mpn = sel.mpn (+)
AND    wk.mpn = res.mpn (+)
AND    wk.mpn = pclub.mpn (+)'
end;
/
```

The above will generate table names automatically based on sysdate. If you still need to pass as variable, then save vijay.sql as

```
declare
begin
execute immediate 
'CREATE TABLE DMS_POP_WKLY_REFRESH_'||&1||' NOLOGGING PARALLEL AS
SELECT wk.*,bbc.distance_km ,NVL(bbc.tactical_broadband_offer,0) tactical_broadband_offer ,
       sel.tactical_select_executive_flag,
       sel.agent_name,
       res.DMS_RESIGN_CAMPAIGN_CODE,
       pclub.tactical_select_flag
FROM   spineowner.pop_wkly_refresh_20100201 wk,
       dms_bb_coverage_102009 bbc,
       dms_select_executive_group sel,
       DMS_RESIGN_CAMPAIGN_26052009 res,
       DMS_PRIORITY_CLUB pclub
WHERE  wk.mpn = bbc.mpn(+)
AND    wk.mpn = sel.mpn (+)
AND    wk.mpn = res.mpn (+)
AND    wk.mpn = pclub.mpn (+)'
end;
/
```

and then run as
sqlplus -s username/password @vijay.sql '20100101'