# Passing Parameters to SQL Query through Batch file doesn't work

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I have a simple sql query which I execute using a batch file. I invoke the batch file by supplying parameters.

SQL

```
    Select empSal from Emp_Master where empID = '&2';
    exit
```

Batch File

```
sqlplus -s myusername/mypass@%1 @E:\fetchEmpSal.sql %2 > E:\fetchEmpSal_log.txt
```

%1 - Would be my db name or instance name. 
%2 - Would be my empId.

This is how I invoke the Batch file. I open CMD, navigate to the path and enter the following.

```
fetchEmpSal.bat mydb 1011
```

Now, the batch file runs ok, but each time it asks for the empID. Is this the correct way of passing parameter to sql through batch file?? Please help

EDIT:

Now when I call the batch file using the above method, the command changes like below.

```
sqlplus -s myusername/mypass@mydb @E:\fetchEmpSal.sql 1011  > E:\fetchEmpSal_log.txt
```

But, 1011 is not passed into SQL as a parameter. This is how it used to work, but I don't know why it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575321/how-to-pass-variable-from-shell-script-to-sqlplus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something here, but couldn't you just change your SQL to the following?

```
Select empSal from Emp_Master where empID = '&1';    -- not &2
exit
```

You're only providing one parameter value to your SQL*Plus script, so it is perhaps not surprising that SQL*Plus is struggling to find a value for `&2`.