# Pull data from Oracle DB into file with sqlplus must provide schema name

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, shell, sqlplus

I am trying to pull data(use sqlplus) from Oracle DB into a file, but as that table's last column is default empty string, how to handle it ?

Note: I have verify the 3rd column existing in Oracle DB, the script works fine on other table if last column is not empty, but for this last column empty table, it failed.

Error information is:

```
[...@... scripts]$ ./myscript.sh
|| TRIM(THIRD_COLUMN) FROM TEST_TABLE
                 *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

The related sqlplus is below:

```
My_Table="TEST_TABLE"
sqlplus -s  ${USER}/${PASS}@${HOST} <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET COLSEP "|"
...some SET here...
SPOOL $FILE
Select TRIM(FIRST_COLUMN)|| '|'
|| TRIM(SECOND_COLUMN)|| '|'
|| TRIM(THIRD_COLUMN) FROM $My_Table;
SPOOL OFF
EXIT
EOF
```

How can I pull the last column together with all other columns especially when it is empty string ? Could someone help to figure out, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error suggest that problem is not column but table that you're passing by variable `$My_Table`. You're passing variables wrong way. Please have a look on that [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575321/how-to-pass-variable-from-shell-script-to-sqlplus). 
`$My_Table` is variable in bash. When you run script first step is running SQLplus and there this variable not exist.

In your case it should be something like:

```
./myscript.sh $My_Table $FILE
```

And in your script use `&1` in place of `$My_Table` and `&2` in place of `$FILE`

And if you build your query like that you don't need to `SET COLSEP "|"` as result of your query is single column so either use `COLSEP` or `||` to concatenate all cols

Comment: i have rechecking the error message and edit in right format, could you have to check again ? thanks and sorry for previous wrong information which may confuse you.

Comment: @Lampard try now. The problem seem to be with wrong way of passin variable

Comment: as I tried, not because of input variable issue, i set the `My_Table="TEST_TABLE"` before sqlplus part, also add it in original post here. Still suspect the issue caused relate to last empty column

Comment: @Lampard so please run sqlplus directly and execute your query without variables. Empty column is not a problem as you can do `select '' from table;`

Comment: @Lampard After that line `sqlplus -s  ${USER}/${PASS}@${HOST} <<EOF` you're in SQLplus `$My_Table` not exists there  and it can't be resolved. You have to set name after SQLplus run. Setting it before makes the same problem.

Comment: you are right, actually, as I test is because i miss the schema name before table name, the right format should be `$schema_name.My_Table`, this is not the empty column issue, just because not find the table at all. But actually, `$schema_name.My_Table` this variable can be declared before `SET` section in sqlplus, it will also work. Anyway, thanks.