# how to pass values to temp table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT p1.*,
      (p1.opening_balance + p1.retained_now - p1.released_now -
       p1.clawbacked_amount - p1.arrears_amount) AS closing_balance
 FROM (SELECT p.channel_org_id,
              t.channel_name,
              p.aggregation_id,
              ((SELECT SUM(amount)
                  FROM t_agent_retention_balance
                 WHERE agent_id IN
                       (SELECT agent_id
                          FROM t_agent
                         WHERE channel_org_id = p.channel_org_id)
                   AND account_type = 5) -
               (SELECT SUM(commision)
                  FROM t_product_commision
                 WHERE aggregation_id < p.aggregation_id
                   AND channel_org_id = p.channel_org_id
                   AND commision_type_id = 1104) +
               (SELECT SUM(commision)
                  FROM t_product_commision
                 WHERE aggregation_id < p.aggregation_id
                   AND channel_org_id = p.channel_org_id
                   AND commision_type_id = 1110) +
               (SELECT SUM(commision)
                  FROM t_product_commision
                 WHERE aggregation_id < p.aggregation_id
                   AND channel_org_id = p.channel_org_id
                   AND commision_type_id = 1122) +
               (SELECT SUM(commision)
                  FROM t_product_commision
                 WHERE aggregation_id < p.aggregation_id
                   AND channel_org_id = p.channel_org_id
                   AND commision_type_id = 1123)
              ) AS opening_balance,
              (SELECT SUM(commision)
                 FROM t_product_commision
                WHERE aggregation_id = p.aggregation_id
                  AND channel_org_id = p.channel_org_id
                  AND commision_type_id = 1104) AS retained_now,
              (SELECT SUM(commision)
                 FROM t_product_commision
                WHERE aggregation_id = p.aggregation_id
                  AND channel_org_id = p.channel_org_id
                  AND commision_type_id = 1110) AS released_now,
              (SELECT SUM(commision)
                 FROM t_product_commision
                WHERE aggregation_id = p.aggregation_id
                  AND channel_org_id = p.channel_org_id
                  AND commision_type_id = 1122) AS clawbacked_amount,
              (SELECT SUM(commision)
                 FROM t_product_commision
                WHERE aggregation_id = p.aggregation_id
                  AND channel_org_id = p.channel_org_id
                  AND commision_type_id = 1123) AS arrears_amount
         FROM t_product_commision p, t_channel_org t, t_commision_type ct
        WHERE t.channel_id = p.channel_org_id
          AND p.commision_type_id = ct.commision_type_id
          AND p.aggregation_id =?
          AND p.comm_status <> 1
          AND p.channel_org_id = ?
        GROUP BY p.channel_org_id, t.channel_name, p.aggregation_id) p1
```

**i want to pass values to ? parameters in p1 temp table how can i achieve this**
in ? place i want to pass p1.x and if i tried to pass values like p1.x=12 after p1 like
`where p1.x=12 and p1.y=23` it is saying p1.x is invalid identifier

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236201/how-can-i-pass-parameter-to-sql-script

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  When you say 'in ? place I want to pass p1.x', do you mean replacing one of the `?` marks with one of the columns in `p1`, e.g. `p.aggregation_id=p1.released_now`?  (I'm not sure this example necessarily makes sense.)  When you say 'I tried to pass values like p1.x=12 after p1', does this mean you tried to add a condition such as `where p1.aggregation_id = 12` to the end of the query?  Are you trying to write something like `stmt.setString(1, "p1.x")` using JDBC?

Comment: yes i tried to add a condition like where p1.aggregation_id=12....it gave me error  @luke

Comment: i am not trying to pass a value of p1 for p.aggregation_id ..i just want to pass normal value but i dont want to hard code it(i wnat to write a query to work with different values)  @luke

Comment: 'i tried to add a condition like ... it gave me error': there are **three** things wrong with that statement: (1) **exactly what** condition did you add?  (2) **where** did you add the condition, and (3) what was the error message?  Also, what are you using to run this query?  SQL*Plus?  SQL Developer?  Toad?  PL/SQL Developer?  JDBC?  Something else?

Comment: i tried to add the condition where p1.aggregation_id=12 and error message was p1.aggregation_id is invalid identifier and i'm running it in plsql developer.....

Comment: **You still haven't told me where you added the condition!**  Incidentally, I added it to the end of the query and I got no error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean, you just want to pass different input values to run the select with.
This is how you do it:

```
select *
from <yourtable>
where <fieldname> = '&1';
```

If you run this query by replacing  with your tablename and  with your fieldname then you will be asked to give a value for &1.
This value can be different everytime you repeat the query.